# php link missing due to to small change in html code

Tags: html, css, styles

Working code without errors:

```
<form action="serverinfo.php">

<p><input type="submit" value="Search Server - NOC" style="width: 500px; height: 30px;"> 

</p>
```

I changed this like below and not working:

```
<form action="serverinfo.php">
</form> 
<a href="#"class="transparent_btn">search server</a>
```

Can you please help me here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you need from it? Send something from a form and submit it to serverinfo.php or are you trying to make it like a hyperlink whichs redirect you to the page of serverinfo.php?

If it is just a hyperlink remove the form tag and do it like this:

```
<a href="serverinfo.php">Search Server</a>
```

If it is a form make sure there is data being submitted from the form. Add some textbox or something, not only a submit button.

Comment: Hi Gio,  your line is working.. my idea is to create a transparent button with CSS..can you please help again

Comment: What kind of transparent? Like there is no background? Or some effects maybe?

Comment: Yes Gio, THere is a background image, i have normal input type as submit working fine. i want to make that normal button to transparent  and move on.

Comment: Target that button with CSS and put border:none; and background:transparent;

Comment: Dear Gio, Thanks a lot for your suggestion.

//below gives my style but got messed up to invoke the php//
<form action="serverinfo.php">
</form> 
<a href="#"class="transparent_btn">search server</a>

<a href="serverinfo.php">Search Server</a>

<form action="serverinfo.php">
//THis is a normal button input which invokes the php perfectly//
<p><input type="submit" value="Search Server - NOC" style="width: 200px; height: 30px;> 

</p>

one is working for style and other is good at deploying php.

my target is to achieve both in one.